# webpack splitchunksplugin minsize not working

Tags: javascript, webpack, webpack-dev-server, webpack-4

This is my `app.js`

`import Test from './test1'`

This is my `test1`

`import('smallest')
var a = 10;
export default a;`

I am not using `splitchunksplugin` because even if we don't use it, it has some default settings.  This is the first 2 default conditions.

- New chunk can be shared OR modules are from the node_modules folder
- New chunk would be bigger than 30kb (before min+gz)

I am wondering why it created another chunk for `smallest` library(this library is less than 30kb before min+gz). Any idea?

Answer (score 1):

When ever webpack encounters dynamic import statement it will always split it out of main chunk. This way you will have entry-points chunk and async split-points chunk ( in case of dynamic import in your code ). The splitchunksplugin is then used to further  optimize/split those chunks and all the default conditions applies there. You can further look into the docs https://webpack.js.org/guides/code-splitting/#dynamic-imports